# Making Laravel understand proxy domain htaccess rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, proxy

I have a setup in Laravel whereby I have different sections of the site powered by one codebase. A section is defined by the first slug of the uri:

`localhost.dev/section1/feature`

`localhost.dev/section2/another/feature`

However, I also have a domain alias/proxy for these so that each section can have its own independent branding and SEO without splitting up the codebase.

`section1.dev/feature` (alias of `localhost.dev/section1/feature`)

`section2.dev/another/feature` (alias of `localhost.dev/section2/another/feature`)

However, Symfony's HTTPFoundation appears to be too smart to be fooled by this proxy, and whenever you use `URL::full()` or `URL::current()`, the domain remains `localhost.dev` despite your browser telling you that you're on `section1.dev` or `section2.dev`

Is there a way to configure .htaccess differently, or is there a way to make Laravel's `URL::full()` or `URL::current()` mirror what's in your address bar?

Answer (score 0):

First: a domain alias is not a proxy.

Second: the `app.url` config option gets used by the application to generate URLs. Try making it an empty string.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the case for me. `URL::current()` or `URL::full()` do not appear to be affected by anything set in app.url. I tried setting it to `http://abcdef.com` and it was not used by those methods. In fact, even using Form model binding to a route seems to ignore what's defined in app.url.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel version 4.1.19